# Why I cant use the populateViewHolder override method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm try to retrieve datafrom `database` in my `fragment` `onViewCreated` method I have used **FirebaseRecylerAdapter** like below

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    }

    public static class AllUsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View view;

        public AllUsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
        }
    }
```

when I use `firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` it wont give me the **`populateViewHolder`** method just give method like below

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllUsers, AllUsersViewHolder>() {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(AllUsersViewHolder holder, int position, AllUsers model) {

            }

            @Override
            public AllUsersViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                return null;
            }
        };
```

Can someone please tell me why this is happening

Comment: what version of firebaserecycleradapter are you using (in the gradle its written)

Comment: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.0'

Comment: There is no populate method in firebaserecycleradapter.java class

Comment: true I will answer you how, in older versions you can use populateviewholder

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The constructor of the `Firebase...Adapter` classes has changed in FirebaseUI version 3. Given this query:

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    .getReference()
    .child("users")
    .equalTo(name);
```

If you're using a version 3 or higher, you use `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`:

```
 FirebaseRecyclerOptions<model_class_name> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<model_class_name>()
                    .setQuery(query, model_class_name.class)
                    .build();
```

Then declare a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(options) {
```

add the variable `options` as above. It is the variable of the class `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`

Then to add items you have to use `onBindViewHolder` since its the latest version of firebase ui:

```
 @Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position, model_class_name model) {
    // Bind the class object to the holder
    // ...
}
```

For more info check this: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database

Comment: @HemalHerath alright add the a variable(options or any name you want) in firebaserecycleradapter, you didn't have that

Comment: Note: above `setQuery` you may have to write this `.setLayout(R.layout.your_layoutrow)`