# Facing challenge using FirebaseRecyclerOption

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47364513/why-i-cant-use-the-populateviewholder-override-method/50536481?noredirect=1#comment88086823_50536481) answer but no one is giving a clear explanation of how to use `FirebaserecyclerOption`. Please I request assistance in giving a complete code example.

```
package com.kevin.postify;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import static com.kevin.postify.R.layout.activity_posts_list;

    // activity class

public class PostsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(activity_posts_list);// activity layout

 //Actionbar
 ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
//set title
   actionBar.setTitle("Posts List");

   //RecyclerView
   mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
   mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

 //set layout as LinearLayout
  mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

 // Send query to FirebaseDatabase

  mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Data");
  }

  //search data
  private void firebaseSearch(String searchText){

   //convert string entered in SearchView to lowercase
    String query = searchText.toLowerCase();

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
  mRef.orderByChild("search").startAt(query).endAt(query + "\uf8ff");

  // here is where I get some errors in implementing firebaserecyclerOptions 
  //and has been myu MAIN issue plaz can someone help here i will apply to 
  //many hanging projects.

  FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PostsListActivity> options =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PostsListActivity>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.activity_posts_list)
                .build();

    // here too I get an error
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                Model.class,
                R.layout.row,
                ViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery
        ) {
            @Override

  // to populate don't think it work in latest version or maybe onBindView
  protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, 
  Model model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), 
  model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
            }
       // viewHolder
            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
    viewType) {

                ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, 
   viewType);

                viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new 
   ViewHolder.ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //Views
                        TextView mTitleTv = 
  view.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
                        TextView mDescTv = 
        view.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
                        ImageView mImageView = 
  view.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
                        //get data from views
                        String mTitle = mTitleTv.getText().toString();
                        String mDesc = mDescTv.getText().toString();
                        Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
                        Bitmap mBitmap = 
        ((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();



//pass this data to new activity
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
  PostDetailActivity.class);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new 
   ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, 
   stream);
                        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                        intent.putExtra("image", bytes); //put bitmap image 
       as array of bytes
                        intent.putExtra("title", mTitle); // put title
                        intent.putExtra("description", mDesc); //put 
 description
                        startActivity(intent); //start activity

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        //TODO do your own implementaion on long item click
                    }
                });

                return viewHolder;
            }
        };



  //set adapter to recyclerview
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);}

 //load data into recycler view onStart

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
super.onStart(); 


 //Firebase adapter which causes error

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
        new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, ViewHolder>(
                Model.class,
                R.layout.row,
                ViewHolder.class,
                mRef
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Model 
model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(), 
model.getTitle(), model.getDescription(), model.getImage());
            }

            @Override
            public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {

                ViewHolder viewHolder = super.onCreateViewHolder(parent, 
viewType);

                viewHolder.setOnClickListener(new ViewHolder.ClickListener() 
{
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        //Views
                        TextView mTitleTv = 
view.findViewById(R.id.rTitleTv);
                        TextView mDescTv = 
view.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
                        ImageView mImageView = 
view.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);  //image view
                        //get data from views
                        String mTitle = mTitleTv.getText().toString();
                        String mDesc = mDescTv.getText().toString();
                        Drawable mDrawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
         Bitmap mBitmap =((BitmapDrawable)mDrawable).getBitmap();



    //pass this data to new activity

                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), 
PostDetailActivity.class);
 ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, 
stream);
                        byte[] bytes = stream.toByteArray();
                        intent.putExtra("image", bytes); //put bitmap image 
as array of bytes
                        intent.putExtra("title", mTitle); // put title
                        intent.putExtra("description", mDesc); //put 
description
                        startActivity(intent); //start activity


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
                        //TODO do your own implementaion on long item click
                    }
                });

                return viewHolder;
            }

        };

   //set adapter to recyclerview
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

 @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

//inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it present
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        firebaseSearch(query);
        return false;
    }
                //query change 

       @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        //Filter as you type
        firebaseSearch(newText);
        return false;
    }
});
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
int id = item.getItemId();

//handle other action bar item clicks here

if (id == R.id.action_settings){
    //TODO
    return true;
}

 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Here is the error I get in android studio console

> Error:(65, 17) error: constructor FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: FirebaseRecyclerOptions
>   found: Class,int,Class,Query
>   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length where T,VH are type-variables:
>
> error
>   T extends Object declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter VH extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder declared in class FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are mixing [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) version 2 and version 3. In the last version, when creating a new instance of `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` you need to pass to the constructor a single argument, which is of type `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` and not four as I see in your code.  Because you have asked for a complete example, **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.

Comment: Will try but it should work the way you have explained

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: yes please re-writing my code above with your solution I will appreciate

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. You should make your own attempt given the information in that example, and ask another question if something else comes up, so me or other users can help you.