# How do i populate a viewholder using firebase ui as populateViewholder has been removed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I was following a tutorial on youtube to make a chat app and this fragment shows the list of friends but this method cant be used anymore. I have tried my whole night putting up the code together but couldn't.

```
public class FriendsFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mFriendsList;

    private DatabaseReference mFriendsDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mCurrent_user_id;

    private View mMainView;


    public FriendsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);

        mFriendsList = (RecyclerView) mMainView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mCurrent_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mFriendsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(mCurrent_user_id);
        mFriendsDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced(true);


        mFriendsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mFriendsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return mMainView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

// I have tried using options here but i failed*

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder> friendsRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Friends, FriendsViewHolder>(

                Friends.class,
                R.layout.users_single_layout,
                FriendsViewHolder.class,
                mFriendsDatabase


        ) {

// This method is no more available

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final FriendsViewHolder friendsViewHolder, Friends friends, int i) {

                friendsViewHolder.setDate(friends.getDate());

                final String list_user_id = getRef(i).getKey();

                mUsersDatabase.child(list_user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        final String userName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                        String userThumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

                        if(dataSnapshot.hasChild("online")) {

                            String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("online").getValue().toString();
                            friendsViewHolder.setUserOnline(userOnline);

                        }

                        friendsViewHolder.setName(userName);
                        friendsViewHolder.setUserImage(userThumb, getContext());

                        friendsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

                                CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[]{"Open Profile", "Send message"};

                                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

                                builder.setTitle("Select Options");
                                builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                        //Click Event for each item.
                                        if(i == 0){

                                            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                            profileIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            startActivity(profileIntent);

                                        }

                                        if(i == 1){

                                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_id", list_user_id);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("user_name", userName);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);

                                        }

                                    }
                                });

                                builder.show();

                            }
                        });


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

            }
        };

        mFriendsList.setAdapter(friendsRecyclerViewAdapter);


    }


    public static class FriendsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public FriendsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setDate(String date){

            TextView userStatusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            userStatusView.setText(date);

        }

        public void setName(String name){

            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);

        }

        public void setUserImage(String thumb_image, Context ctx){

            CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(thumb_image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(userImageView);

        }

        public void setUserOnline(String online_status) {

            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_online_icon);

            if(online_status.equals("true")){

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {

                userOnlineView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }

        }


    }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46859983/i-cant-find-populateviewholder-method-in-firebaserecycleradapter-class

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I actually know this thing but I am too rookie to apply this on my above fragment. I have applied it to one of my other activity but i failed in this one.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It would be really grateful of you if you can help me

Comment: If you are interested, **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is how you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.